# How to insert a primefaces input text dynamically?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a field called `numberOfGuests` which takes an integer value. When I submit the page, I want to insert as many `p:inputText` fields in the next page as the `numberOfGuests` value dynamically. `ui:repeat` allows me only to iterate over a collection. I would like to know how I can do that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create a collection (or, easier, an array) of size `numberOfGuests`.

E.g. in a view scoped bean:

```
private Integer numberOfGuests; // +getter+setter
private String[] guests; // +getter

public void submit() {
    guests = new String[numberOfGuests];
}
```

with

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText value="#{bean.numberOfGuests}" />
    <p:commandButton value="submit" action="#{bean.submit}" update=":guests" />
</h:form>

<h:panelGroup id="guests">
    <h:form rendered="#{not empty bean.guests}">
        <ui:repeat value="#{bean.guests}" varStatus="loop">
            <p:inputText value="#{bean.guests[loop.index]}" />
        </ui:repeat>
        <p:commandButton value="save" action="#{bean.save}" />
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

The result is just displayed in the same view as that keeps the view scoped bean instance alive and the input fields are referencing the value by index instead of by `var` as `String` in this example is immutable. If it were a complex object like `Guest`, then just bind them the "usual" way like `value="#{guest.name}"` or so.

Comment: In the line `guests = new String[numberOfGuests];` numberOfGuests always returns 1 for me. So my array size is always 1. Any idea why that might be? I am creating the array `guests` in a different class and accessing `numberOfGuests` of the other class through an object.

Comment: I am suspecting it is because I am creating a new object of class `Bill`, which has `numberOfGuests`, in my other class `TailorTip` and accessing it using `bill.getNumberOfGuests()`. It is taking the default value of `numberOfGuests` which is 1.

Comment: I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or not but the example code did not work for me until i added <p:ajax event="change"/> inside of the p:inputText. I am using PF 6.0 so perhaps something changed?

anyway just wanted to let people know in case the example does not work for you.